# Extract ColumnReference info from QueryPlan xml

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have large xml which is nothing but a queryplan. I need to extract column informations from that.

In that xml there is a tag like below,

```
<ColumnReference Table="[TestTable]" Schema="[dbo]" Database="[Mydatabase]" Column="FirstName" Alias="a"/>
```

I want to extract table,schema,column information. ColumnReference is buried inside multiple different tags. But I need all of ColumnReference tags regardless of hierarchy

select  table,schema,column from Columnreference

part of xml for example:

```
<RelOp EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRebinds="0" Parallel="1" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="92.6757" AvgRowSize="349" EstimateCPU="0.0439447" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRows="179.753" LogicalOp="Repartition Streams" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" NodeId="3">
<OutputList>
<ColumnReference Table="[REALESTATECONTRACT2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="ODS_REGIONCODE" Alias="[REC2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[REALESTATECONTRACT2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PRIMARYLOCATIONTRIIDTX" Alias="[REC2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PATHTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTIDSY" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTFLOORTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTBUILDINGTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="NAMETX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING1]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="STATEPROVTX" Alias="[BLD]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="COUNTRYTX" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="CITYTX" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="ACTIVESTARTDA" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
</OutputList>
<Parallelism PartitioningType="Hash">
<PartitionColumns>
<ColumnReference Table="[REALESTATECONTRACT2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PRIMARYLOCATIONTRIIDTX" Alias="[REC2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="NAMETX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PATHTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTIDSY" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTFLOORTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTBUILDINGTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="CITYTX" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING1]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="STATEPROVTX" Alias="[BLD]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="COUNTRYTX" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="ACTIVESTARTDA" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
</PartitionColumns>
```

Comment: ...and your problem is? In other words, why don't you just use a SAX parser and process the `ColumnReference` when you encounter it?

Comment: am I able to use it from sql server?

Comment: Sorry, missed that you're working entirely inside SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will help you:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<RelOp EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRebinds="0" Parallel="1" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="92.6757" AvgRowSize="349" EstimateCPU="0.0439447" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRows="179.753" LogicalOp="Repartition Streams" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" NodeId="3">
<OutputList>
<ColumnReference Table="[REALESTATECONTRACT2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="ODS_REGIONCODE" Alias="[REC2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[REALESTATECONTRACT2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PRIMARYLOCATIONTRIIDTX" Alias="[REC2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PATHTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTIDSY" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTFLOORTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTBUILDINGTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="NAMETX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING1]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="STATEPROVTX" Alias="[BLD]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="COUNTRYTX" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="CITYTX" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="ACTIVESTARTDA" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
</OutputList>
<Parallelism PartitioningType="Hash">
<PartitionColumns>
<ColumnReference Table="[REALESTATECONTRACT2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PRIMARYLOCATIONTRIIDTX" Alias="[REC2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="NAMETX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PATHTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTIDSY" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTFLOORTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[SPACE]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="PARENTBUILDINGTX" Alias="[SP]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="CITYTX" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING1]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="STATEPROVTX" Alias="[BLD]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="COUNTRYTX" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
<ColumnReference Table="[BUILDING2]" Schema="[Tririga]" Database="[TRI_INTL_CERT]" Column="ACTIVESTARTDA" Alias="[BLD2]"/>
</PartitionColumns>
</Parallelism>
</RelOp>';
```

--I use two variables, you can adapt this to your needs

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100)='[BUILDING2]';
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)='COUNTRYTX'
```

--This will use `Xpath / XQuery` to trigger a *deep search* (`//`) for `<ColumnReference>`, but it will return only rows, where the predicate is fulfilled.

```
SELECT a.query('.')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'//ColumnReference[@Table=sql:variable("@tableName") 
                                    and @Column=sql:variable("@ColumnName")]') A(a);
```

### UPDATE

This query will return the line in columns:

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100)='[BUILDING2]';
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)='COUNTRYTX'

SELECT a.value('@Table','nvarchar(max)') AS TableName
      ,a.value('@Schema','nvarchar(max)') AS SchemaName
      ,a.value('@Database','nvarchar(max)') AS DatabaseName
      ,a.value('@Column','nvarchar(max)') AS ColumnName
      ,a.value('@Alias','nvarchar(max)') AS Alias
FROM @xml.nodes(N'//ColumnReference[@Table=sql:variable("@tableName") 
                                    and @Column=sql:variable("@ColumnName")]') A(a)
```